# Android Studio - button that opens activity - another button in it that opens new activity

Tags: android

This is my first post on this site so I'll be short!

I'm new in Android Studio, and trying to make an app.. Problem occures here: 
I create a button an code it so it redirectes to new activity when pressed. That work's fine on emulator. Then in that new activity I create another button that redirects to another acrivity and code it on the same way as previous button (ofc I change names and all of that) but when running app on emulator first button works just fine and then I press on second button. It gives me a app force close error.. I don't get it, why, Android Studio does not report any error in code, but that new button just wont work.

I created those buttons with this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Anyone knows solution?

```
content_my.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.dario.mojaaplikacija.MyActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_my">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_vjezbe"
        android:text="@string/button_vjezbe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="vjezbe" />

</LinearLayout>


MyActivity.java

    public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public final static  String EXTRA_MESSAGE ="com.example.dario.mojaaplikacija";
    public void vjezbe(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BenchPress.class);
       // String varijabla = editText.getText().toString();
        //intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, varijabla);
        startActivity(intent);



content_bench_press.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.dario.mojaaplikacija.BenchPress"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_bench_press">

    <Button
        android:text="@string/button_o_benchu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="benchA"/>

</LinearLayout>





BenchPress.java

public class BenchPress extends AppCompatActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.dario.mojaaplikacija";

     public void benchA (View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BenchA.class);
        startActivity(intent);



content_bench.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/conten"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.dario.mojaaplikacija.BenchA"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_bencha">

</RelativeLayout>



BenchA.java

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(BenchPress.EXTRA_MESSAGE);


strings.xml

    <resources>
    <string name="app_name">MojaAplikacija</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="button_vjezbe">Vježbe</string>
    <string name="title_activity_display_message">MyMessage</string>
    <string name="title_activity_bench_press">BenchPress</string>
    <string name="button_o_benchu">Bench</string>
    <string name="title_activity_bench">BenchA</string>
</resources>
```

RED code I get when clicking on that second button:

```
01-09 22:27:23.091 2431-2431/com.example.dario.mojaaplikacija E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.dario.mojaaplikacija, PID: 2431
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dario.mojaaplikacija/com.example.dario.mojaaplikacija.BenchA}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at com.example.dario.mojaaplikacija.BenchA.<init>(BenchA.java:30)
                                                                                    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

BenchA.java

```
package com.example.dario.mojaaplikacija;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

public class BenchA extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bencha);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(BenchPress.EXTRA_MESSAGE)
```

;

Comment: DaxHR, can you share with us the code you're using?

Comment: Could you post the code in which it breaks, it'll be easier to identify the problem

Comment: There are a few things you can do to help find the cause of your problem, especially if you are new to android studio. The best thing to do in a crash is to check under logcat (android tab at the bottom). Scroll until you find your particular error. For now, go ahead and post what you have in your project.

Comment: OK guys, code is up! Note that I only coppied the  code I wrote, not whole files.

Comment: I'm about 90% sure it's a null pointer exception with either one of the getIntents returning null or grabbing something by the wrong name. Which activity does it crash by?

Comment: By BenchA.java or content_bench.xml
Android Studio doesn't report any error at all, the app crushes on emulator when I press that second button

Comment: It might be that your 2nd onClick method is in the wrong place. Android studio will not grey out the onClick method benchA, but if it's not in the correct activity it'll crash because it can't find that method. You can't be certain yet. Can you click on the android tab, then click on logcat, and find a large chunk of red text, copy and paste that? Logcat has valuable error information. I can help you if you can find that. Let me know if you need help getting there.

Comment: Aha thank you I'll post an answer. Remember to always check it when an error occurs

Comment: Wait can you post your whole BenchA.java class? I'd like to see if there is an easier fix to why getIntent() is returning null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make this two methods:**

The onClick method for the first button:

```
public void onClickFirstButton(View view){
    //your code go here...   
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, the_name_class_of_new_activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);//you can start the new activity at any time with this line
}
```

> For the second button is the same method(change the name of method and
>   put the name of your second new activity.

```
public void onClickSecondButton(View view){
        //your code go here...
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, the_name_class_of_second_new_activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);//you can start the new activity at any time with this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at com.example.dario.mojaaplikacija.BenchA.<init>(BenchA.java:30)
```

This tells you to check line 30 in BenchA

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dario.mojaaplikacija/com.example.dario.mojaaplikacija.BenchA}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

This tells you that you have a null pointer exception. You can read about it on stackoverflow some more but it basically means you tried to call getStringExtra on intent, but the intent object is null.

`Intent intent = getIntent();` returns null. It couldn't find it. That's why the subsequent line crashes. **Wrap the following line in  `if (intent != null)`** to avoid NullPointerException

To solve the problem, I don't want to recommend you stray too far from the tutorial but one option is to pass in a Bundle and in your new activity's onCreate, you can to get the bundle.

Another thing: in the BenchPress class you never passed it any String extras. So you are trying to get a string that was never on the intent to begin with. String message will return null;

EDIT: Now that you've posted your class, it appears that getIntent is floating in as an attribute of the ActivityClass. Sure, Java is ok with that since you are merely defining this in those two lines. But if you were to write an instruction, for instance, print out your message or show text, it cannot compile. Drop the two lines `Intent intent...` and `String message...` into your onCreate. *I strongly believe this is the reason getIntent() returned null. The class didn't have access to getIntent(), but when you override the oncreate method, you do have access to getIntent()*

EDIT:

Here's what you should do instead, this is what you intended to grab:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bencha);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(BenchPress.EXTRA_MESSAGE)

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: full BenchA.java added!
when I add that if(intent != null) i get error: cannot resolve symbol intent..
String on MyActivity.java was there wroten as a comment, bcos in tutorial there was adding some text, and that lines were refered to that text..

Sorry, I am new to all this, can you just tell me step by step what to do?

Comment: I think you may have wrapped it like `if(intent != null) { Intent intent = getIntent(); }` which is incorrect since intent hasn't been defined yet. Can you try putting it around the `String message...` part? This will push away the error, but it won't solve what you are looking for. Hang on and I'll help you find a way to get the string extra without any risk of crashing

Comment: wrapped it arround String message part - errors: Identifier expected, unexpected token, unknows class 'intent'

Comment: Wait and I'll update my answer. I didn't read the class, but the reason why is because that bit of code is outside of a method floating in the java class, you cannot put instructions there

Comment: Make sure you understand that in a Java class, if you are outside a method, you are not actually executing anything. You merely defined an Intent and a String that your methods can now grab and use, but if you put like an if statement, the class is like "i don't know when to use this." It MUST be in a method. You can read up more on Java classes if you are confused by this. Don't feel bad, I made this mistake about 2 months ago on SO and got downvoted to oblivion :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe this!
I solved it!!

My BenchA.java now looks like this:

```
package com.example.dario.mojaaplikacija;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

public class BenchA extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bencha);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                Intent intent = getIntent();

                if (intent !=null) {
                    String message = intent.getStringExtra(BenchPress.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
                }    }
        });
    }

}
```

just putted that if statement inside the class and the button works!

Still getting some red code:

```
01-10 00:03:56.469 2567-2584/com.example.dario.mojaaplikacija E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xabef7ee0

01-10 00:03:58.755 2567-2584/com.example.dario.mojaaplikacija E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xabef9290
```

Don't know what that means, but the main thing is that it's working!!!!

Comment: Hi-Five! A couple of things, though: You want to move getIntent() and String message lines out of onClick and probably before FloatingActionButton line. What it's currently doing is that when the fab is clicked, then it will get the intent and message, but you clearly wanted to grab this data *outside* of the listener. The red errors didn't crash your app, mostly I'd ignore those. I urge you to fix these two things and understand what is happening. It may be uncrashing, but the message isn't where you want.

Comment: Another thing that is helpful to me when I'm debugging my app is Android Studio's debug mode. Set a red breakpoint on the left margin. Then click the little bug and it'll attach a debugger to your app, allowing you to view potential NPEs

Comment: You mean like:

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent !=null) {
            String message = intent.getStringExtra(BenchPress.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        }

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Comment: Yes. The reason you don't have an error anymore is 1) you moved getIntent() into a method and out of a class 2) now that it's in oncreate, you have access to getIntent(). In your current code, it doesn't give you an error, but now when you click the fab button it grabs the intent and makes a message. This doesn't make any sense, probably what you intended was getting the message after you switch your activity.

Comment: Wow.. As I said, I'm new to this so this is kinda too tehnical for me.. Alt least I expected that it would be easier to add a simple button and don't crash you app.
Anyway, thank you for your help and fast response! You helped me a lot! :)